# Pandas - Create a DataFrame of Maximum Key-Value Pairs

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame of key-value pairs for a collection of IDs. The columns in the DataFrame are (ID, Key, Value).

```
data = {
    "ID":{0:1,1:1,2:1,3:2,4:2,5:2,6:3,7:3,8:3,9:4,10:4,11:4},
    "Key":{0:"A",1:"B",2:"B",3:"A",4:"B",5:"B",6:"A",7:"B",8:"B",9:"A",10:"B",11:"C"},
    "Value":{0:28,1:94,2:107,3:67,4:70,5:70,6:24,7:77,8:87,9:24,10:83,11:83}
} 
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: DataFrame]

I am trying to create a new table where the columns are the unique Keys, and their associated value is the maximum value for each ID:

[image]

So far I am able to create a DataFrame that contains the desired maximum values:

```
max_data = data.loc[ data.groupby(["ID", "Key"])["Value"].idxmax() ]
```

[image]

However, I am not sure the best way to get a DataFrame where the columns are the unique Keys with their associated values. This is what I have so far, but I am trying to avoid a loop:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(max_data["ID"].unique(), columns=["ID"])
for key in max_data["Key"].unique():
    result = result.merge(
        max_data.loc[max_data["Key"] == key][["ID", "Value"]],
        how="left",
        on="ID"
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `pivot_table`

```
data.pivot_table(index='ID',columns='Key',values='Value',aggfunc='max')
Out[22]: 
Key     A      B     C
ID                    
1    28.0  107.0   NaN
2    67.0   70.0   NaN
3    24.0   87.0   NaN
4    24.0   83.0  83.0
```